# Clear contents of any cell in column that contain a double quote in the text string

Tags: string, vba, excel, replace

I need to clear the contents of any cell in column `K` that contains a double quote (`"`) in the text string.  The text strings will differ some will say `3" hose`,  some will say `10" road` so it won't be the same and it is only within that column that I need the contents of the cell cleared (not deleted, I don't want the remaining data to move).

Here is what I have tried:

```
Sub Macro4()
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("K2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$V$3225").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="=*""*" _
      , Operator:=xlAnd
    Range("K45").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Range("E3").Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("A4").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Select column k then `Ctrl+h` then `Find what: *"*` and `Replace with:` then hit `Replace All`

Comment: The problem is that I recorded that.  I dont' know how to edit it to select the resulting contents and clear since the results won't always start with row 45 :( and for some reason, it caught some items but not others.  Like the cells that contain 3" hose were brought up in the filter but 10" road did not...

Comment: Columns("K:K").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="*''*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

Comment: @RavenclawExcelStudent [STOP USING `SELECT`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Answer (score 1):

Answer posted in comments:

```
Columns("K:K").Select
Selection.Replace What:="''", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
  ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Although you should [never use `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) so I would use:

```
Columns("K:K").Replace What:="''", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
  ReplaceFormat:=False
```